# Gulp-sass is not throwing any errors, but my scss is not display in the browser

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm setting up gulp-sass to use in my project but am having difficulty getting it to work. I have tried almost every link on here to set up my gulp tasks and watch, but can't seem to figure out why my scss styles are not loading in the browser (I am running it locally).

I have basic styles in my .css stylesheet and my .scss stylesheet for testing, and the only styles that get triggered are the ones in .css - I have no error messages in the browser or when I run `gulp sass` in the root of my project.

[sources tab in the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsC3E.png)

[running gulp sass in the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol6Dj.png)

I set up my gulp-sass task with help from here:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-set-up-gulp-sass-using-the-command-line-if-youre-a-beginner-17729f53249

My project structure is as follows:

```
ProjectName
-> app
--> css
---> styles.css
--> fonts
--> images
--> js
--> scss
---> main.scss
-> node_modules
gulpfile.js
index.html
package-lock.json
package.json
```

my gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");

gulp.task("sass", function () {
 gulp.src("app/scss/*.scss")
 .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
 .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"));
 });

 //compile and watch
  gulp.task("sass:watch", function() {
  gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", ["scss"]);
 });

 gulp.task("sass", function(done) {
     console.log("Hello!"); done(); }
 );
```

and I linked my css stylesheet in the index  as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/styles.css">`.

I have used gulp and sass before at work, but everything was set up already and this is my first time setting it up on a solo project. Any and all help is greatly appreciated :) thank you.

Comment: As written your `main.scss` file will be compiled to `main.css` which you don't link to in the html.  Do you want to have the `main.scss` end up as your `styles.css`?

Comment: agh, this was my mistake. originally, I had them both called main.css, I'll keep them as style.scss/style.css though. do I have to create the .css file or will it automatically create it for me based on the .scss?

Comment: Sass will rename `style.scss` to `style.css` automatically.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Am I supposed to have an active styles.css file and have it linked in my HTML? Its unclear to me if the sass creates it or if I have to create it and the sass will fill it with styles.

Comment: Sass will create `styles.css` if you have a `styles.scss` first.  In your html link to the `styles.css`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. It seems to be working despite an "Did you forget to signal async completion?" error,  but only if I run ```gulp sass``` after every style change.

Comment: Notice that I had put a `return` statement in the `sass` task which will prevent that `async completion` error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your final scss transpilation to produce `styles.css` you have to do either of two things:

1. Either start with `styles.scss` instead of `main.scss` and sass will automatically name it `styles.css` or
2. Modify your `sass` task to rename the resultant file:

   ```
   var rename = require("gulp-rename");

   gulp.task("sass", function () {
      return gulp.src("app/scss/*.scss")
       .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
       .pipe(rename('styles.css`))
       .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"));
   });
   ```

[If you are using gulp v4 (run `gulp -v`), your `watch` task won't work. Try:

```
gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", gulp.series("scss"));
```

in that function and get rid of the second `sass` task altogether.]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have renamed both files to be styles.scss and styles.css - I have also replaced ```gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", ["scss"])``` and removed the sass task with your suggestion.

It still doesn't work, though. No errors either.

Comment: Yes, the new gulp.watch in my answer replaces the second line of your `sass:watch` task.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Unfortunately the changes haven't fixed my problem. It's so hard to debug when there's no errors, too. Gah.

Edit: without the ```sass``` task, I get an error "The following tasks did not complete: sass Did you forget to signal async completion?"